# Don't let website get submitted if pagerank is lower than 2

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have manage to build up a script for checking and not letting the user submit his website if his website's pagerank is not lower than 2, but still encounter problems:

PHP - getpagerank.php

```
<?php
  include('components/GooglePageRanker.php');
  $url = filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
  $googlePageRanker = new GooglePageRanker();
  echo $googlePageRanker->getPagerank($url);
?>
```

This works properly, tested in my browser and i am getting a number, the actual pagerank of the website from domain.com/getpagerank.php?url=xyz123456.com, which results correct in a number, the pagerank.

Javascript - getpr.js

```
function checkPR() {
 var $btn = $('#buttonsubmit');
 var $input = $('#urlpr');
 var url = $.trim($input.val());
  $.get('getpagerank.php?url='+url, function(data){
   var pr_int = parseInt(data);
   if ($.trim(data) == '' || pr_int < 2) {
    alert('PageRank of this domain/page is less than 2!');
    $btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   } else {
     $btn.removeAttr('disabled');
   }
  }, 'text');
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="infos">
 <input onblur="checkPR()" type="text" class="input_text_metas" name="url" value="http://" id="urlpr" /> 
 <input type="button" class="button" value="{'webmasterSubmitWebsite_button_metas'|lang}" id="metaTagButton" /> 
 <img src="{"/templates/$templateName/images/icone_info.gif"|resurl}" alt="" class="aide" title="{'webmasterSubmitWebsite_website_url_tooltip'|lang}" />
</div>
```

ACTUAL PAGE:

Just choose a category and add a website with a lower pagerank than 2 example xyz545.com, after you do onblur it won't happen anything. It should alert the user in a a pop up alert that his pr is lower than 2 and disable submit button.

Where am i mistaking?

Comment: Uhhh, Google no longer uses Pagerank, you know right? http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/5535/Why-Google-Page-Rank-is-Now-Irrelevant.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seriously, learn to use debug tools such as the browsers error console.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://www.blowhits.com/getpagerank.php?url=http://xyz545.com

Your function probably is never called, because the page never returned a result. According ti http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ :

> A callback function that is executed **if the request succeeds**.

Comment: There is a bit of a problem with my server currently sorry

Comment: It doesn't work with http://, it works simple with www and non-www.

Comment: Rule #1: make any AJAX request as robust as possible.

Comment: Could you please be a more explicit in terms of code.

Comment: Found the problem, it was a server problem,mod_security rule that needed to be white listed. Would not have done it without it you telling me for the http://.